# YA Sci Fi/Fantasy book - Tax Collector from another plane or planet taking words

Tags: story-identification, books

A young girl plays Scrabble with her family and has to use words related to books she's reading (i.e.: for *Jungle Book* she could use Mowgli, tiger, India, etc). She's also part of a secret club and it turns out the entity running this club was a "tax collector" from another plane or planet where words are "collected" as taxes. The girl notices because she is no longer able to use more specific or complex words in her family Scrabble games.

This would have been read in the fairly early 90s, probably published late 80s/early 90s